# Prove that $\mathbb{Q}^{\times}$ not isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}^{n}$

Tags: group-theory

$\mathbb{Q}^{\times}$ is the group of rational number without $0$ under multiplication, and $\mathbb{Z}^{n}$ is the free abelian group of rank $n$. Show that $\mathbb{Q}^{\times}$ not isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}^{n}$. I tried to assume that there is an isomorphism and to get a contradiction.. didn't succeed

Comment: $\Bbb Q^\times$ has torsion, but free abelian groups do not. In fact $\Bbb Q^\times$ is isomorphic to $\Bbb Z_2\oplus \bigoplus  \Bbb Z$ where the sum is over countably many copies of the integers.

Comment: That's even better, you should put this as an answer, even if it same the same as @Meelo wrote, and as what anyone could wrote. (Bet.)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Suppose you had a homomorphism $f:\mathbb Q^{\times}\rightarrow\mathbb Z^{n}$. Notice that $(-1)^2=1$ thus $f(-1)^2=1$. The only solution to $x^2=e$ (where $e$ is the identity) in $\mathbb Z^{n}$ is $e$, thus $f(-1)=f(1)=e$, meaning no homomorphism is injective and the groups are not isomorphic.

(To be clear, notice that $x^2=e$ in $\mathbb Z^n$ would more commonly be written as $x+x=0$, but I chose to write it multiplicatively to aid seeing the connection between $(-1)^2=1$ (in $\mathbb Q^{\times}$) and $x^2=e$ (in $\mathbb Z^{n}$))

Comment: It is very unorthodox to denote the zero of $\Bbb Z^n$ as $1$. =)

Comment: I edited its answer properly to address that, but the guy apparently refused my edit...

Comment: @RobertGreen It is better to comment to the poster on such minor detail (which is not incorrect!) rather than to "force" the edit oneself.

Comment: I would tend to see this as coding with other people. The code does not belong to anyone, and anyone is free to "edit" change it, provided that this edit preserves the function/results etc of the code. Btw, I'm not forcing anything, as he can (and he did) refuse. What I say is that my edit is valid as it corrects what he put in the first place. Instead of validating the edit, he preferred to give an answer that is *stil* really cumbersome : "$x^2 = e$ in $\mathbf{Z}^n$"... In which serious place have you ever seen this kind of stuff ? ;-)

Comment: I don't see the point of writing $x^2 = e$ to aid seeing the aforementionned connection, as we all know (OP included) what a morphism of groups is... I'm downvoting.

Comment: @RobertGreen Do you think this answer is not useful?

Comment: @PedroTamaroff You are completely off mate. I edited/downvoted because I think one doesn't help to understand the group morphism concept by changing the natural group notation. One helps by defining what a morphism is, and saying that one groupe is additive and the other is multiplicative. And because I think that someone "light" in maths coming accross this notation will be confused by the $x^2 = e$ happening in something he "knows" to have an additive structure. End of the discussion on my side.

Comment: @Robert It had not initially occurred to me that the notation $x^2=e$ was at all unnatural and, after seeing your edit, I chose to keep the notation, but to note that it was not standard. I didn't like your edit because it didn't seem helpful to say one group is multiplicative and the other is additive - those properties aren't intrinsic to the group, so I'm unconcerned with them (esp. since I usually think of $\mathbb Z^n\cong \langle a_1,\ldots,a_n | a_ia_j=a_ja_i\rangle$). Your edit was valid, but it conflicted with my intention - a comment (or even separate answer) would have been better.

Comment: @Meelo no problem ! ;-) Out of curiosity : how do you usually think of $\mathbf{Z}$ then ? Because if I come up with the functor representing $\mathbf{Z}^n$ that I'm identifying $\mathbf{Z}^n$ with, things may become fun ! Especially for such a *BASIC* question, isn't it ? ;-)

Comment: @RobertGreen Your downvote is still not justified. Just because Meelo chose one notation over another doesn't mean his answer is not useful, and he also clarified why he did it, and how this notation is not the usual one. In fact, this is the only completely correct answer so far. You also didn't answer my question: do you think this answer is *not* useful?

Comment: @PedroTamaroff As it is, I wouldn't repeat this answer (as it is, again) to someone, let alone hypothetical newcomers in the study of groups. So I don't find it useful, truthfully. And as I said, it is because of the multiplicative/additive stuff, which could trouble *some* people that will have an answer, but that could be troubled by the notation. (Years ago I taught to people preparing *agrégation* in France, and even some of them would be troubled by that.) Would that be adressed, I would un-downvote. (PS : we could chatify this long discussion, as it is the "rule".)

Comment: @RobertGreen It is addressed in the last parenthetical remark of the answer.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff Be why leave it in it then, for Christ's sake !? Would *you* give the very same answer to someone, honestly, Pedro ?

Comment: @RobertGreen If someone can work simultaneously with a "multiplicative" group $\Bbb Q^\times$ and map it to an "additive" group $\Bbb Z^n$, then they shouldn't have  a headache from using different notations. At any rate, this is getting too tangential, and I will delete this comment in a while.

Answer (score 12):

$\mathbf{Q}^{\times}$ is generated by the set of positive prime numbers and $-1$ so it contains (a groupe isomorphic to) $\mathbf{Z}^{\mathscr{P}}$ where $\mathscr{P}$ is the set of positive prime numbers. $\mathbf{Z}^{\mathscr{P}}$ is not of finite rank over $\mathbf{Z}$ whereas any $\mathbf{Z}^n$ is, so there's no possible isomorphism $\mathbf{Q}^{\times} \rightarrow \mathbf{Z}^n$, for any $n$, as any such arrow would give an infinite free family in $\mathbf{Z}^n$, namely, the family image of $\mathscr{P}$ by the supposed isomorphism.

To put if in a "fashion" way the morphism $$v : \mathbf{Q}^{\times} \rightarrow \{\pm\}\times \mathbf{Z}^{\mathscr{P}}$$ defined by $v(x) = \left( \textrm{sign}(x), \left(   v_p(x)\right)_{p\in \mathscr{P}} \right)$ where $v_p$ is the $p$-adic valuation function for $p\in \mathscr{P}$, is an isomorphism.

This relies on the fact that $\mathscr{P}$ is infinite - fact admitted here. ;-)

Comment: Your argument is that  $\mathbf Q^\times_{>0}$ not finitely generated while $\mathbf Z^n$ is. Although this is correct, showing that there is no set of generators of cardinality less than the cardinality of the set of primes (and $-1$) can be unpleasant.

Comment: @Myself Why? It's the fundamental theorem in action; clearly if a given $p_i$ appears in a member of $\mathbb{Q}^\times$ then it has to be in one of the generators...

Comment: Is it really that unpleasant? Any finite set of elements of ${\mathbb Q}^\times$ can only involve finitely many primes in their numerators and denominators, so cannot generate the whole group.

Comment: @Myself forgot to put $-1$, sorry. Nothing is unpleasant actually, as you may see in my edited answer

Comment: Ah maybe it's not quite so unpleasant as I thought :-) For a minute I thought there would be lcm's and gcd's all over the place; but that is for $(\Bbb Q,+)$.

Comment: Honestly I think it's far better to say $x^2=e$ in $\mathbb Z^n$ than it is to call elements of a group "guys."

Comment: You see, here you compare a figure a speech (that you may disagree with, of course !) with something that is not the mathematical equivalent of an english figure of speech. You'll find mathematicians calling guys elements of a set, it is informal indeed. You won't find any of them noting multiplicatively the additive law of $\mathbf{Z}^n$, and I even think that it is stupid to do so : you don't not help to understand the group morphism concept by changing the natural group notation. You help by saying what a morphism is, and that one guy is additive and the other multiplicative.

Comment: Robert, there are details missing here. If you want to show that $\Bbb Q$ is not finitely generated, you need to show every finitely generated subgroup is proper. This is not hard by invoking the fundamental theorem of arithmentic, since these generators can only provide with finitely many primes, but your argument as it stands is not entirely correct. For example, I can take a set of (infinite) generators $2,5,6,7,11,13,\ldots$, where $3$ is missing. But of course it is not missing from the whole group, since $6/2=3$. You need to be careful about your wording!

Comment: I am NOT saying that $\mathbf{Q}^{\times}$ is not finitely generated, even if it's true, I'm saying that it cannot be free of finite rank over $\mathbf{Z}$. And I show that it is generated by $\{-1\} \times \mathscr{P}$ - fact shown by showing that any generating guys missing leads to a contradiction, the freeness being obvious, but as it may apparently not being obvious, I will edit.

Comment: The last isomorphism is correct, but the first argument is not (in particular the opening sentence of the post). You're saying that $\Bbb Q^\times$ is generated by primes and $-1$. But what do you mean when you say "suppose $-1$ is not needed to generate"? This is not clear, and is not a proof. And the statement that the family is free is false, since $-1$ is torsion. You might mean that the primes and $-1$ are a minimally generating set, which is true. But unless you modify the argument, I don't see how you are using this to prove anything.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff For sure it does not mean that you have to let your duck 20 min on therm. 10 to cook it medium rare. ;-) It means, clearly, that any familly not containing it ($-1$, not the duck !) will miss the $<0$ numbers, that is, will generate something included in $\mathbf{Q}_{+}^{\times}$, as in Derek Holt's remark, who rightly pointed I forgot to add $-1$. For the torsion part you're right, edited. (Cannot do it faster from mobile, sorry.)

Comment: @RobertGreen The family $\{-2,2,3,\rm primes\ldots\}$ doesn't contain $-1$, but it generates all of $\Bbb Q^\times$.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff you're right indeed, but I meant "every subfamily of $\{-1\}\cup\mathscr{P}$", sorry for the mistake, $\mathscr{P}$ being the set of positive primes of the integers.

Comment: @RobertGreen I still don't see how that corrects the answer. If you can, please correct the argument. Your answer has currently 8 upvotes so I wouldn't want people to copy the argument thinking it is correct.